# Storing all values in the array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A` with shape `(2,4,1)`. I want to calculate the mean of `A[0]` and `A[1]` and store both the means in `A_mean`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[[1.7],
        [2.8],
        [3.9],
        [5.2]],

       [[2.1],
        [8.7],
        [6.9],
        [4.9]]])

for i in range(0,len(A)):
    A_mean=np.mean(A[i])
print(A_mean)
```

The current output is

```
5.65
```

The expected output is

```
[3.4,5.65]
```

Comment: `A.mean((1, 2))`

Comment: the problem is that you overwrite `A_mean` at each iteration of your loop, instead of appending a new value. @Warkaz's answer is the best solution, but a minimal fix to your loop would have been to first initialize `A_mean=[]` and then use `A_mean.append(np,mean(A[i])` in the body of your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[[1.7],
        [2.8],
        [3.9],
        [5.2]],

       [[2.1],
        [8.7],
        [6.9],
        [4.9]]])
A_mean = []

for i in range(0,len(A)):
    A_mean.append(np.mean(A[i]))
print(A_mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

The for loop is not necessary because NumPy already knows how to operate on vectors/matrices.

solution would be to remove the loop and just change axis as follows:

```py
A_mean=np.mean(A, axis=1)
print(A_mean)
```

Outputs:

```py
[[3.4 ]
 [5.65]]
```

Now you can also do some editing to remove the brackets with `[3.4  5.65]`:

```py
print(A_mean.ravel())
```

Comment: Excellent answer, taking full advantage of NumPy's internal optimizations. Note that if OP really wants the final results in a list, they could use `A_mean = list(np.mean(A, axis=1).ravel())`, but keeping the results in an array probably makes more sense for further processing with NumPy tools.

Comment: @joanis Thanks for the compliment, I already did add the part about ravel() (last line of code) as that was requested format by the OP

Comment: Yes, indeed, I noticed your added `ravel()` and that was a good idea, thanks for that edit!